# Couldn't output the price and discount correctly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am doing an assignment given by my lecturer, all the output is correct but the price and payment after discount is not correctly output, i don't know where is the problem.. can someone help me with this? i still trying to understand the coding..

Here is my coding..

```
import java.util.*;

public class Apps {

public static void main (String args []) {

    double price=0.0, discount=0.0, total=0.0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

System.out.print("Please input your name : ");
String name = sc.next();

System.out.print("What is your status [A-Adult | C-Children] : ");
String status = sc.next();

System.out.print("Please enter type of treatment[1-Restoration | 2-Extraction | 3-Scaling] : ");
int type = sc.nextInt();

if(status=="C"){
    if(type=='1'){
        price = 6.0;
        discount = price * 0.90;}
    else if(type=='2'){
        price = 15.5;
        discount = price * 0.90;}
    else{
        price = 4.0;
        discount = price * 0.90;}}
else if(status=="A"){
    if(type=='1'){
        price = 7.5;
        discount = price * 0.95;}
    else if(type=='2'){
        price = 18.0;
        discount = price * 0.95;}
    else{
        price = 5.5;
        discount = price * 0.95;}}

System.out.println("        \n\n                                   HUSNA DENTAL");
System.out.println("      ====================================================================");
System.out.println("                  Name                   : "+name);
System.out.println("                  Type of treatment      : "+type);
System.out.println("                  Payment before discount: "+price);
System.out.println("                  Payment after discount : "+(total=price-discount));
System.out.println("      ====================================================================");
}
}
```

The output is like this..

Please input your name : deena

What is your status [A-Adult | C-Children] : C

Please enter type of treatment[1-Restoration | 2-Extraction | 3-Scaling] : 1

```
                               HUSNA DENTAL
  ====================================================================
              Name                   : deena
              Type of treatment      : 1
              Payment before discount: 0.0
              Payment after discount : 0.0
  ====================================================================
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues:

1) `if(status=="C"){`

should be

```
if(status.equals("C")){
```

Use `equals()` for String comparison. Same applies for other String comparisons you have in code.

2) `type == 1` for int comparison NOT `type=='1'`, same applies for other places in your code.

Comment: I've corrected the things you told me just now, and it works ! :D thankyou so much for your help yea :)

Comment: err, may I ask again? its the same coding, but in C++ language, still couldn't output the price and the payment after discount.. of course i can't use `equals()` right?

Comment: @deenaiena: Sorry! Not expert in c++.

Comment: Ohh yea? its okay lah, I'll try to ask others, thankss :D

Answer (score 0):

For Object comparison use [Object#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method. `==` compares only references.

So instead of if(status=="C") use if("C".equals(status)). Comparing with "C" will save you from [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

And for int `''` is not required.

Another point you might need, use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of double while calculation.

Comment: I just start learning Java, so I don't know that BigDecimal can be used in the coding, sorry but thanks a lot for tips, I will for sure try it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Apps {

public static void main (String args []) {

    double price=0.0, discount=0.0, total=0.0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

System.out.print("Please input your name : ");
String name = sc.next();

System.out.print("What is your status [A-Adult | C-Children] : ");
String status = sc.next();

System.out.print("Please enter type of treatment[1-Restoration | 2-Extraction | 3-Scaling] : ");
int type = sc.nextInt();

if(status=="C"){
    if(type=='1'){
        price = 6.0;
        discount = price * 0.90;}
    else if(type=='2'){
        price = 15.5;
        discount = price * 0.90;}
    else{
        price = 4.0;
        discount = price * 0.90;}}
else if(status=="A"){
    if(type=='1'){
        price = 7.5;
        discount = price * 0.95;}
    else if(type=='2'){
        price = 18.0;
        discount = price * 0.95;}
    else{
        price = 5.5;
        discount = price * 0.95;}}

System.out.println("        \n\n                                   HUSNA DENTAL");
System.out.println("      ====================================================================");
System.out.println("                  Name                   : "+name);
System.out.println("                  Type of treatment      : "+type);
System.out.println("                  Payment before discount: "+price);
System.out.println("                  Payment after discount : "+(total=price-discount));
System.out.println("      ====================================================================");
}
}
```

Here are the issues

- When comparing strings, always use `equals` method and not `==` as `equals` method checks for string equality and `==` checks whether both references refer to same object
- you are already reading the value in `int` form by using `int type = sc.nextInt();` so you should compare using `if(type==1)` and not `if(type=='1')`

Comment: Is it better to use equals method or I just should use it if it is for strings? btw, thankss :)

Comment: If you want to check the equality of objects, then you must use equals method. I have explained the difference in the answer :) And yes, if you find the answer useful, you can upvote it.